# My PC won't turn on if I send the magic packet through mobile data and PC is turned off (S5 state) for more than 4 minutes

Tags: wake-on-lan

I have configured my router to port forward my PC on port 9 in order to receive the magic packet for WoL. If my phone is connected to my home wifi the will turn on (no matter in what power state is the PC and how long the PC was turned off).

If my phone is connected to mobile data the PC will turn on only if I send the magic packet in less than 4 minutes, after that nothing happens. If my PC is in hibernate mode or sleep mode it will turn on no matter how the PC was in one of these modes and on which way the magic packet was sent.

I have tried everything (turn off any Ethernet adapter power saving, editing the registry to keep internet adapter on while in S5, editing local group policy, uncheck and check again (after seeing that there is no difference) let system turn off this device, turn on any wake on lan related setting in internet adapter properties, setting up wake on lan in bios and update it).

I've observed that in S5 the PCs IP address disappears after 4 minutes even if the led on the router for my PCs lan stays on and blinks.

My motherboard is a Gigabyte B450 DS3H V2 with a Realtek GBE gaming Ethernet adapter build in. The router is router modem combo ZTE f6600R with a FiberHome router where my PC is connected(almost all the settings are not available on that router because is in bridge mode).

I've also tried connecting the PC directly to the router modem combo ending up with having the same results.

I've also turned off fast start up and use Ultimate Performance profile (for other stuff).

I don't know what to do to fix this.

Comment: You could update (carefully) the BIOS to the latest version  [F65b](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-V2-rev-1x/support#support-dl-bios) from Sep 21, 2023. What is your Windows version?

Comment: Already did, nothing changed unfortunately 

Comment: My os is Windows 11 Pro

Comment: From which box do you see that the PC's IP address disappears after 4 minutes? The router? Which make is the router and is its firmware fully updated? Does it perhaps have some setting to check the connected devices every 4 minutes?

Comment: I've shutdown the PC,connect to the router web interface where I can see in real time the devices connected on wlan and lan,I've counter and result that my PC's IP address disappears from my router modem combo ZTE f6600R lan list in 4 minutes,test if I my starts on wol and the result was negative,but If I send the magic packet in less than 4 minutes it starts.

Comment: As I said before the FiberHome router settings are all related to the Zte router"this setting is not available while in bridge mode" all I can see on it is if the router has internet connection and that's all

Comment: Talking about firmware update I don't know where to find them(I have tried in their web site and found nothing about it,also tried some YouTube tutorials about zte updates with no luck)

Comment: This seems like an old router, and I also haven't managed to find any download for it. It may have an update function in its interface. Or, if it comes from the ISP, their Support might be able to help. Otherwise, if you can loan another router from somewhere, try it and see if it helps.

Comment: You are right,my router modem combo is from my ISP.To be honest I have search for that update section in the routers web interface and guess what,I doesn't have one.

Comment: To be honest this is one of the newest modem router at my ISP provided so I don't think they have a better one since it has optically fiber and 5Ghz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to configure your router to have a static/permanent ARP table entry for the PC you want to wake.

ARP table entries typically expire and are auto-deleted after 2-4 minutes of inactivity, and the only way to get them back is for the target device to respond to ARPs, which most devices don't do when "off".

So your router is probably *trying* to forward the magic packet onto the LAN, but can't, because it can't address it at the Ethernet layer, because it doesn't know the Ethernet MAC address for that target IP address anymore, because that ARP table entry expired and is not getting renewed.

Since the format of the WOL magic packet contains the target device's MAC address inside the packet (in the payload, not necessarily the header), your WOL-magic-packet-sending utility will use that information to fill in the destination MAC address on the Ethernet header of the magic packet when sending it on the local LAN (or it will address it to a broadcast MAC address). That's why there's generally no need for static ARP mappings when sending magic packets from within the LAN, and thus why this is only a problem from outside the LAN.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149713/discussion-on-answer-by-spiff-my-pc-wont-turn-on-if-i-send-the-magic-packet-thr); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.